# Javascript is working on Safari, but fails on others

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser, xml-parsing

There is some problem that I can't find out why the code worked on Safari, but failed on other browsers.

There is the [html part](http://github.com/CarolHsu/gmap/blob/master/gmap_demo.html)
and the main [javascript part](http://github.com/CarolHsu/gmap/blob/master/scripts/main.js).

#### The main problem that I find is:

While executing the function `downloadurl(url, function)`, cannot find the XML tags "Info", and the markers array length is 0 on many browsers. However, it's ok on Safari. The part of javascript code is like:

```
downloadUrl("http://travel-taoyuan.tycg.gov.tw/content/travel/xmlcontentlist1.aspx", function(doc) {
    var xml = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Info");
    ......
```

To alert markers, it will return "0".
And actually it should be "174"(Safari's result).

*Thanks for answering my question.*

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, seems to be a syntax error. Different browsers will use a different syntax, and so it won't execute (or at best, not properly if your lucky).

Try something along the lines of....

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://travel-taoyuan.tycg.gov.tw/content/travel/xmlcontentlist1.aspx",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("theMainTagName"); //TODO: this is the main tag ^(see note)
        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
          { 
          //TODO: code to handle each xml element
        //this is the code to get the value from a particular tag: x[i].getElementsByTagName("theTagName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
          }
        </script>
```

NOTE: ^the 'main' tag is, for example, in the case of [this xml document](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml), the 'main' tag is 'CATALOG'

Hope this helps. Sorry if it's not very clear, been a while since I worked with xml/javascript. Comment if you want further explanation

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I found the question is that XML file's structure, different Structure (even if encoding) would lead to javascript can't parse it successfully. Otherwise, some browsers such as Chrome can't accept cross-server XML http request for safety, to solve this problem at least you have to keep the XML file on the some server.